# How do I pass an LLVM backend parameter to Xargo?

Tags: rust, llvm

I'm compiling a Rust application for the AArch64 architecture and I need to pass the LLVM backend parameter [`-mgeneral-regs-only`](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/UsersManual.html) so that the code uses only general purpose registers.

How do I pass the parameter to Xargo as I need to cross-compile the application?

[As suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52665505/155423), I tried to run the command with `RUSTFLAGS` but got an error about unknown command line arguments:

```
RUSTFLAGS='-C llvm-args=-mgeneral-regs-only' xargo build --target aarch64-unknown-none
error: failed to run `rustc` to learn about target-specific information

Caused by:
  process didn't exit successfully: `rustc - --crate-name ___ --print=file-names -C llvm-args=-mgeneral-regs-only --sysroot /home/.xargo -Z force-unstable-if-unmarked --target aarch64-unknown-none --crate-type bin --crate-type rlib --crate-type dylib --crate-type cdylib --crate-type staticlib --crate-type proc-macro` (exit code: 1)
--- stderr
rustc: Unknown command line argument '-mgeneral-regs-only'.  Try: 'rustc -help'
rustc: Did you mean '-mark-data-regions'?
```

Comment: `-mgeneral-regs-only` isn't an LLVM backend parameter; it's a command line argument to clang. You need to find the actual backend parameter.

Comment: @Shepmaster any idea where to look for? I tried to look at output of clang compilation infomation; unfortunately I didn't show.

Comment: Nope. My best guess is that you will need to read the source of clang to figure out how it does what it needs to.

Comment: That being said, your latest edit has transformed a good question into not a good question. **You got an answer for how to pass a backend parameter to LLVM**, but have not upvoted it or accepted it, and now you have edited your question to be about two distinct things. I'd suggest removing your edit and asking a new question (in [tag:clang] [tag:llvm]) about how to map a generic clang command line argument to LLVM (or the specific one you are interested in).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [the Xargo documentation about compiling the sysroot with custom `rustc` flags](https://github.com/japaric/xargo#compiling-the-sysroot-with-custom-rustc-flags). `rustc` allows setting LLVM flags via the `-C` switch:

```
$ rustc -C help
...
-C            llvm-args=val -- a list of arguments to pass to llvm (space separated)
...
```

You should be able to pass that in with `RUSTFLAGS='-C llvm-args=-mgeneral-regs-only' xargo build`.

Comment: Note that `-mgeneral-regs-only` isn't an LLVM backend parameter; it's a command line argument to clang. Presumably this works if OP finds the right parameter.